# Upload Images to Notion Page Content-Block (Notion API, Python)

Tags: notion-api

I'm working on a way to upload local images(JPEG) to a page in Notion via Notion-API with Python.
I already converted the picture in base64 and now I want to add it in a block, inside a existing page. I know theres a way to upload images from a URL but first I want to try if this is possible.

I tried different URLs of the api to which i send my call, because I'm not completely sure how to set up this up properly. It's my first try to directly interact with an API, so this is a bit of a struggle for me.

This is the part of my Code in which I have problems with. I think it might be just a problem with the json formatting, the url, or I completely missed how to to do it properly.

```
        # Image as base64
        image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_bytes).decode("utf-8")

        url1 = "https://api.notion.com/v1/blocks/input_page_id/children"
        url2 = "https://api.notion.com/v1/pages"

        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {notion_api_key}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Notion-Version": "2022-06-28",
            "accept": "application/json"
        }

        data = {
            "parent": {
                "type": "page_id",
                "page_id": "input_page_id" },
            "children": {
                "type": "image",
                    "image": {
                        "type": "file",
                        "file_ids": [
                            {
                                "url": "data:image/jpeg;base64," + image_base64
                            }
                        ]
                    }
            }
}


        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
        print(response.json())
```

The first URL "url1" is invalid and I tried a few variations of it, but as I understand it should be the right endpoint to update(in my case create) a block and a page in notion is also a block, so I just put in the page id here.
The error message i get for "url2" is as follows:

```
{'object': 'error', 'status': 400, 'code': 'validation_error', 'message': 'body failed validation: body.parent.database_id should be defined, instead was `undefined`.'}
```

If uploading the images as base64 isn't possible anyway, i would try to use an Cloud Storage like AWS S3 or something which is designed for private use like Dropbox.